# Implementing OSGi plugins into an existing source

Tags: java, plugins, osgi

I am looking to make plugins of various tools for an existing project (Minecraft client) and it seems peple suggest OSGi the most, is it possible to add OSGi plugins to the source.
Aka a plugin loaded in could do something in the game, such as make the player jump, crouch, or move forward.

Do I have to create my own plugin system from scratch? If so how does one start especially with an exsisting project like modifying minecraft source code

Comment: the Mincraft client is written in Java? If it is, i can write you a brief overview what you need to do to start.

Comment: It is indeed, one of their devs releases something called 'MCP' (Mineacraft coders pack) after the patches occasionally and its a tool that decompiles and allows easy recompiling. ANd anything would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you get more familiar with extending Minecraft before you start looking into how to modularize it.

Comment: I actually have done alot of work with minecraft, quite a reasonable amount fo experience with it, and java aswell. Plugins are a new world im trying to explore, and I want to incorporate them at the start instead of building something then re-coding it into plugins.

Answer (score 3):

OSGi **is** us a plugin system. So to answer your question, no, you don't have to create one yourself.

If you have an existing (Java) application, adding OSGi is trivial because this is standardized in the [launching api](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/launch/package-summary.html). A few lines of code will do this.

That said, linking your existing application into the OSGi framework can be a bit more complex. You will have to make your types on your application side available to the *bundles* in the OSGi framework as well as your *services*. You will have to *export* the packages via the  framework and register services via the BundleContext of the Framework object you created. This can be done but is quite cumbersome over time.

A better approach is to run your *own* code as a bundle in the OSGi framework. Just take your code as is, wrap it with all its dependencies that are not OSGi bundles and let [bnd](http://bnd.bndtools.org/) do its magic.

I **strongly** advise you to take a look at OSGi enRoute. Unfortunately, the long life of OSGi means there are lots of old tutorials in the web that are plainly wrong or totally lack the best practices that have been found over time. Though OSGi enRoute can be a bit pedantic sometimes, it does follow what we know inside the OSGi of how to develop bundles. The most important lessons be:

1. Always use services to interact with other modules
2. Did I say always use services to interact with other modules?
3. Always use Declarative services
4. Always use (versioned) package imports

With [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org) you can have a stand-alone application up and running minutes after you downloaded [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/), including full continuous integration build on Travis. You will find lots of tutorials, examples, app notes, and the service catalog as well

If you plan to make this Minecraft client open source then I am very interested in helping you out if you use [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org) since this would be a very nice [example](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.examples) for the OSGi enRoute example suite? Don't hesitate to context me on the OSGi enRoute [Forum](http://enroute.osgi.org/forum.html).

Comment: I would love to make it open source and I will post on the forum where we can discuss this further

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on hybrid application that has C++ side (UI) and Java side (90% of logic and using OSGi), so i can give some advice.

If you want to use OSGi, i would suggest Eclipse platform, because you will get even more than OSGi (for example amazing extension-point/extension registry).

With Eclipse platform you will have in your code something similar to standard java entry point `void main(String[] args)` where your coding begins. This is the method [org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication.  start(IApplicationContext context)](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fequinox%2Fapp%2FIApplication.html). You can implement this method as you want, you are not restricted to anything, but you will have the nice OSGi runtime.

So how to start?

1. Download [Eclipse IDE](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2)
2. According to tutorial from Lars Vogella install e4 tools (point **4. Install the e4 tools**)
3. You should be able now to create new Plug-in project in Eclipse (in wizard dialogs use radio button `Eclipse version: 3.5 or greater`, no rcp application, no contribution to ui, no template).
4. Now in Eclipse go `New->Other` and create **Product configuration** (select your plugin project you created before and use radio button `Create a configuration file with basic settings`.
5. Now you need to create two extensions ([org.eclipse.core.runtime.products](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_core_runtime_products.html) and [org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_core_runtime_applications.html)) and use these extensions in your **.product** file (the Product and Application textboxes).
6. Now you can run your app with `Launch an Eclipse application` link in **.product** file.

It is quite hard to understand for beginner but later as you will get more familiar with all the concept about OSGi and Eclipse platform, you will greatly benefits from them when building complex applications.

You can read a lot in tutorials from Lars Vogella http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipse.html

Comment: Thanks for the information, I think i understand how to get started on a blank project from the various tutorials on OSGi online, but how would i incorporate it into an exsisting project?